# phpunit 4.07 not installing the php files

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing, phpunit

For the last 24 hours I've been all over the internet searching for a solution to my problem, I'm using ubuntu 12.04LTS. When I run tests using the wordpress testing suite i get

```
"PHP Warning:  require_once(PHPUnit/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/anver/mybook/myweb/wordpress-tests/includes/bootstrap.php on line 7
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/anver/mybook/myweb/wordpress-tests/includes/bootstrap.php on line 7"
```

I understand that the system was not able to find the Autoload.php file. I checked my pear configuration to get the php dir using

```
pear config-show | grep 'php_dir'
```

so i got

```
PEAR directory php_dir /usr/share/php
```

I added this path to the php.ini includes path, to make sure I'm using the right php.ini file I ran

```
php --info | grep 'onfiguration'
```

I installed phpunit by

```
sudo pear channel-discover components.ez.no
sudo pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
sudo pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
sudo pear update-channels
sudo pear upgrade --alldeps
sudo pear install --alldeps phpunit/PHPUnit
```

everything installed successfully and when i run

```
phpunit --version
```

i get PHPUnit 4.0.7 by Sebastian Bergmann.

The problem is when i cd into /usr/share/php there is no directory called PHPUnit created with all the php files and autoloader in it. So I tried to manually create the directory and install it but still didn't put any php files into the directory, I also tried chmodded the directory permission to 777 and that didn't work too.

I've done almost everything like removed pear completely from the system and reinstalled it several times, removed phpunit several times and reinstalled but with no luck.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 1):

Atlast found a solution after so many hours of breaking my head on the internet.

First thing is that wordpress official unit testing framework is not updated to use the latest phpunit php code. So what I did was use the latest phpunit binary from pear and use the old php package from the git repository. Steps explained below.

1. Install the latest phpunit 4.07 as of this writing using pear
2. go to https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/tree/3.7
3. Download the zip file to your home directory and unzip it
4. copy the directory called PHPUnit to /usr/share/php the location may
   vary acccording to your linux distro
5. chmod the dir to 755
6. sudo pear install phpunit/PHP_CodeCoverage
7. sudo pear install
8. phpunit/PHP_Timer
9. sudo pear install phpunit/PHPUnit_MockObject

   To get a list of all available pear extensions for phpunit you can use 
   sudo pear list-all -c phpunit

Now you can go to the wordpress-tests directory and run phpunit and everything should be alright now. Enjoy ! If you have any questions let me know.